# How can I draw multiple circles in a Canvas via binding

Tags: wpf

I want to draw ellipses according to the points in circles property in a canvas(or any other control suitable for this issue).

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Point> circles {get; set;} = new();
}
```

But there is no porperty called ItemSources for a Canvas control. So how can I do this, thank you~!

Comment: In addition to what is explained in the answers to the duplicate questions, you do not even need to bind Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top in an ItemContainerStyle. Just put a Path in the ItemTemplate with an EllipseGeometry as Data. Bind the EllipseGeometry's Center property like `<EllipseGeometry Center="{Binding}" .../>`.